# RadioListTile: Problema al seleccionar una opción - Flutter

Tags: flutter

al querer seleccionar una opción de una lista RadioListTile, no la selecciona... es decir creo que el problema es que no actualiza el valor de mi groupValue.

Esta es la lista

[image]

Al querer seleccionar no pinta el circulo.

Este es mi codigo:

```
 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return RadioListTile(
                      title: Text(lista_proyectos[index].nombre),
                      value: lista_proyectos[index].id,
                      groupValue: selected,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          selected =value ;
                        });
                      });
                }
                 
            )
```

Inicializo mi variable selected asi:

```
 int? selected;
```

Answer (score 0):

Se necesita un poco más de detalle sobre tu código, pero te puedo dar ciertas recomendaciones:

- Primero, tu variable "lista_proyectos" cámbialo a "listaProyectos" (flutter maneja de esta forma la nomenclatura y si es en inglés mucho mejor).
- Tu variable "selected" lo has nombrado en inglés y tu variable "lista_proyectos" en español, no combines dos idiomas.
- Sobre tu error, si has declarado tu variable dentro del método "build", no va a funcionar, ya que cada vez que cambie el estado tu widget, el método "build" se vuelve a disparar, o sea que se va a volver inicializar tu variable "selected" y no se va a guardar el anterior valor. Tu variable "selected" lo puedes declarar fuera de tu método "build".